# Error when displaying data in a datalist from sqldatasource in asp project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sqldatasource

I am building a website for a class and have come across an error that I can not find the solution to. I have a dropdownlist on the page that displays the cutomer name and sets the selected value to the customer id selected from a sqldatasource (data tables from access database - [**fig1**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0cyu.jpg) (this works fine as I have tested it before I added the second sqldatasource). I add a datalist control to the page and a second sqldatasource for the datalist to bind to. I configured the datasource using the configure data source wizard as shown in [**fig2**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0vdL.png) I then use the wizard to test the data returned by the query and see that it works, the wizard shows that the data that I wanted is returned. So I bind the datalist to the data source and now the itemtemplate (in the html source view) contains data bound labels that will show the values:

```
Products.Name:
<asp:Label ID="Products_NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Products.Name") %>' />
<br />
Technicians.Name:
<asp:Label ID="Technicians_NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Technicians.Name") %>' />
<br />
Incidents.DateOpened:
<asp:Label ID="Incidents_DateOpenedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Incidents.DateOpened") %>' />
<br />
Incidents.DateClosed:
<asp:Label ID="Incidents_DateClosedLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Incidents.DateClosed") %>' />
<br />
Incidents.Description:
<asp:Label ID="Incidents_DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Incidents.Description") %>' />
```

The labels are now bound to the data returned from the second source....or so it would seem. When I run it and select a customer that should return the data that is being selected in the sqldatasource select statement, my program crashes and gives this error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Products'.

I do not understand why it is saying that the datarowview does not contain a column with that name when the sqldatasource clearly returns it when I test it in the wizard. Can anyone please help?

P.S. Sorry for the links to imgur...apparently you have to have a higher rep to post pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and the generated HTML was NOT prefixed with the table name like in your code.

I hand-added the table name and reproduced your error.

So, if you have duplicate column names like you do, you need to modify the SQL statement to use an alias:

```
Products.Name as Products_Name
```